# Vertex AI pipeline not using reserved resources of GPU instances

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I created compute engine reservations of double GPU instances, with the following config:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHMLu.png)

However, when "machine used" are below "Total Machines Reserved", Vertex AI pipeline job does not seem to consume reserved GPU instances, and the jobs keeps waiting for instance to be provisioned. The machine config for the job is as follows. As far as I can tell it matches up with the Reservation.

```json
{
  "workerPoolSpecs": [
    {
      "machineSpec": {
        "machineType": "a2-highgpu-2g",
        "acceleratorType": "NVIDIA_TESLA_A100",
        "acceleratorCount": 2
      },
      "replicaCount": "1",
      "diskSpec": {
        "bootDiskType": "pd-ssd",
        "bootDiskSizeGb": 100
      },
      "containerSpec": {REDACTED}
}
```

Meanwhile I can create GPU instances through Compute Engine  with no problem.

I'd like to understand why Vertex AI is not using available VM reservations of GPU instances and keeps waiting for instances to be provisioned.

Answer (score 0):

Vertex AI uses a separate system called "persistent resource"

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-persistent-cluster#gcloud

It's a beta feature, and unfortunately it does not support automatically using reserved resource like Compute Engine, which makes it complicated for running Kubeflow pipeline on VertexAI